# Don't hide toggled div

Tags: javascript, html

I have several divs that I'm using buttons to reveal (i.e. - toggle on and off) but I'm trying to get the behavior to change slightly. Instead, I want them to toggle on, and toggle off the others (which is currently happening) but I don't want the current div to toggle off if the button for that div is pushed again. Currently, when you push the button for a div, it is revealed, hiding any others. If you push that same button again, it toggles the div off so no content is visible. I'd like the current div to remain on. So, pushing a button shows it's div, but doesn't turn it off. This is what I'm using at the moment.

```js
var divs = ["Div1", "Div2", "Div3"];
        var visibleDivId = null;
        function divVisibility(divId) {
          if(visibleDivId === divId) {
            visibleDivId = null;
          } else {
            visibleDivId = divId;
          }
          hideNonVisibleDivs();
        }
        function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
          var i, divId, div;
          for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divId = divs[i];
            div = document.getElementById(divId);
            if(visibleDivId === divId) {
              div.style.display = "block";
            } else {
              div.style.display = "none";
            }
          }
        }
```

```html
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="divVisibility('Div1');">Div1</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="divVisibility('Div2');">Div2</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="divVisibility('Div3');">Div1</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
<div id="Div1">
    Div1 Content
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" style="display: none;">
    Div2 Content
    </div>
    <div id="Div3" style="display: none;">
    Div3 Content
    </div>
</table>
```

Any ideas how I can keep the displayed div from toggling off when it's button is pushed again?

Comment: Well you're deliberately setting `visibleDivId` to `null` if the clicked button matches the currently visible div - so that's why it's disappearing. You could just get rid of this condition and just have the `else` (express as `if (visibleDivId !== divId)`. But really this is FAR too much, and too complex, code for a very simple task. Just toggle some classes and set the classes to mean visible or not in your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to loop either. Here's a simple way to toggle:

```js
function toggleDiv(divId) {
  const div = document.getElementById(divId);
  const visible = div.style.display === "block";
  div.style.display = visible ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="toggleDiv('Div1');">Div1</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="toggleDiv('Div2');">Div2</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="toggleDiv('Div3');">Div3</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
<div id="Div1">
    Div1 Content
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" style="display: none;">
    Div2 Content
    </div>
    <div id="Div3" style="display: none;">
    Div3 Content
    </div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi instead of seting it to null if equals, just return it imnediatly

```
if(visibleDivId === divId) {
        //visibleDivId = null;
        return;
      } else {
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach if you are interested. 
Uses event and a data-for attribute.

```js
// Simple hide all function, using a class identifier to get all Divs to hide.
const hideAll = () => document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach(e => e.style.display = 'none');

// Use event delegation, then if we add or remove buttons it still works
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // if one of our buttons was clicked, do something.
  if(e.target.matches('.divButton')) {
    // Hide all first.
    hideAll();
    // Show the div, identified using the data-for attribute.
    document.querySelector(`#${e.target.dataset.for}`).style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```html
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="divButton" data-for="Div1">Div1</button></td>
      <td><button class="divButton" data-for="Div2">Div2</button></td>
      <td><button class="divButton" data-for="Div3">Div3</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
<div id="Div1" class="content">
    Div1 Content
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" class="content" style="display: none;">
    Div2 Content
    </div>
    <div id="Div3" class="content" style="display: none;">
    Div3 Content
    </div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two functions for this. Just set the div corresponding to `divId` to be visible and hide the rest. Then, it doesn't matter how many times you click the same button, that div will be shown.

```js
var divs = ["Div1", "Div2", "Div3"];
function divVisibility(divId) {
  for (var div of divs) {
    if (div === divId) {
     document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
     document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button onclick="divVisibility('Div1');">Div1</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="divVisibility('Div2');">Div2</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="divVisibility('Div3');">Div3</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
<div id="Div1">
    Div1 Content
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" style="display: none;">
    Div2 Content
    </div>
    <div id="Div3" style="display: none;">
    Div3 Content
    </div>
</table>
```